# How to fetch the id of an item in Django when using JSON to fetch from the database

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a Django template whereby I am looping through several items in the homepage. When an item is clicked, a modal which I have included by importing it should be shown and data related to the clicked item displayed. I am using JSONResponse to prepopulate the modal. Once the modal is shown, I want to create a checkout session which will require the id of the item being referred to in the modal. I am stuck at how to get the id.
Here is the script for showing the modal and prepopulating it:

```
let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
modal.style.display = "none";

function modalHandler(val, content_id) {
  if (val) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = data.subtotal;
        document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = data.taxes;
        document.getElementById("website_fee").innerHTML = data.website_fee;
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data.total;

        fadeIn(modal);
      }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "/modal-content/" + content_id + "/", true);
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    fadeOut(modal);
  }
}
```

Here is the views.py which returns the JSON data:

```
def modal_content_view(request, content_id):
    my_model = get_object_or_404(MyModels, content_id=content_id)
    print(f"the model is {my_model.username}")
    data = {
        'subtotal': my_model.username,
        'taxes': '2.60',
        'website_fee': '0.87',
        'total': '23.47',
        'content_id':my_model.content_id
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Here is the script that is supposed to fetch the data when the checkout button is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
       
        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch("{% url 'checkout' content_id %}", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
              amount: "{{ cost }}" * 100,
              description: "{{ title }}",
              gig_id: "{{ gig_id }}",
            }),
        })
        .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(session) {
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
        }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Here is the view that handles the content_id passed from the script above:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request, content_id):
    model = MyModels.objects.get(content_id=content_id)
    subscription = Subscription(model=model, is_subscribed=False, user=request.user)
```

And here is the onclick function that triggers the modal to show:

```
onclick="modalHandler(true, '{{content.model.content_id}}')"
```

My question is how do I pass the 'content_id' from the modal to the script that handles checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not working as I wanted, I found a temporary solution to this. I soled the issue by placing the javascript inside the for loop where I want to get the content_id of the item. Here is how the script not looks

```
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                              console.log("Button clicked")
                              fetch("{% url 'checkout' model.content_id %}", {
                              method: 'POST',
                              data: JSON.stringify({
                                amount: "{{ cost }}" * 100,
                                description: "{{ title }}",
                                gig_id: "{{ gig_id }}",
                              }),
                              })
                              .then(function(response) {
                              return response.json();
                              })
                              .then(function(session) {
                              return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
                              })
                              .then(function(result) {
                              if (result.error) {
                              alert(result.error.message);
                              }
                              })
                              .catch(function(error) {
                              console.error('Error:', error);
                              });
                              });
```